# dateutil: No module named 'dateutil' error when Pandas installing using pipenv

Tags: python, pandas, pipenv, python-dateutil, pipenv-install

I installed pandas usng

> pipenv install pandas

command when i run my script getting errors as

> ImportError: Unable to import required dependencies:
> dateutil: No module named 'dateutil'

and checked pipenv graph command and got following

> pandas==2.0.3

- numpy [required: >=1.21.0, installed: 1.25.1]
- python-dateutil [required: >=2.8.2, installed: ?]
- pytz [required: >=2020.1, installed: 2023.3]
- tzdata [required: >=2022.1, installed: 2023.3]

I tried to install dateutil manually

> pipenv install python-dateutil

Still issue not solved.Why pipenv failed to install python-dateutil. I seen an closed issue in github [github issue](https://github.com/dateutil/dateutil/issues/957)

Comment: Pls post your code

Comment: @gtomer import pandas as pd; df = pd.read_excel("excelfilename.xlsx", sheet_name="BPR");print(df)

Comment: Are you sure this is the line of code that gets this error?

Comment: @gtomer getting error on import

Comment: Please post your full script

Comment: @gtomer I just imported pandas 'import pandas as pd' and getting error on the same line

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254627/discussion-between-akhil-viswam-and-gtomer).